# How to track delayed jobs in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, amazon-ec2, delayed-job

If I understand how the [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) well, so I have a method and I can call it with Delayed job. In this case will be put this record regarding to this "job" into the table **delayed_jobs** and at the same time will be automatically ran a daemon that will process one record by another one in this table.

The structure of the table look like this:

```
  create_table "delayed_jobs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   :default => 0, :null => false
    t.integer  "attempts",   :default => 0, :null => false
    t.text     "handler",                   :null => false
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.string   "locked_by"
    t.string   "queue"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end
```

Now, here's the task I would like to use the **delayed jobs** algorithm. Users can upload files on my website. These files can be huge - like 400MB for example and I want to use **delayed job** for this purpose.

So, a user pick a file he want to upload, a record will be put to the `delayed_jobs` table and now, I would like to tell to this user, that his/her file is processed. But when will make an upload a couple of users at the same time, let's say 5, how can I recognise, that the upload of the user "A" is still in progress? How to add own column to the **delayed_jobs** and how to write there some information?

Because it looks like everything related to Delayed Job is running on the background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [Custom job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs) with which you can store extra data (like `user_id`). You can also utilize [Hooks](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks) to do something when the job succeeds via `success` method.

For example:

```
class FileUploadJob < Struct.new(:user_id, :filename, :file)
  def perform
    # upload the file
  end

  def success(job)
    # notify user of success
  end
end
```